# GetKeyState() false positive only on German keyboard layouts

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, keyboard-shortcuts, setwindowshookex

When using [`GetKeyState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate) to check whether a key is pressed, I'm getting a strange false positive only on German keyboard layouts. The check is within a low-level keyboard hook.

The specific key that seems to be causing issues is `RMenu` (the right Alt key).

In the hook proc below, pressing `RMenu+P` on a US keyboard will populate the `pressedKeys` dictionary with `Menu`, `RMenu`, `P`. Whereas pressing the same keybinding on a German layout will populate the dict with `Menu`, `RMenu`, `ControlKey`, `LControlKey`, `P` (where `ControlKey`, `LControlKey` are falsely reported as down).

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

internal static class Program
{
  private const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
  private const uint WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;

  [STAThread]
  private static void Main()
  {
    _ = SetWindowsHookEx(HookType.WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeybindingHookProc, Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.BaseAddress, 0);

    // `SetWindowsHookEx` requires a message loop within the thread that is executing the code.
    Application.Run();
  }

  private static IntPtr KeybindingHookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
  {
    var shouldPassThrough = nCode != 0 || !((uint)wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || (uint)wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN);

    // If nCode is less than zero, the hook procedure must pass on the hook notification.
    if (shouldPassThrough)
      return CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, nCode, wParam, lParam);

    var inputEvent =
      (LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent));

    var pressedKeys = new Dictionary<Keys, bool>
    {
      [inputEvent.Key] = true
    };

    foreach (var key in Enum.GetValues<Keys>())
    {
      if (IsKeyDown(key))
        pressedKeys[key] = true;
    }

    // Check for arbitrary keybinding (Right alt + P):
    // !!!!!
    if (!pressedKeys.ContainsKey(Keys.P) && !pressedKeys.ContainsKey(Keys.LMenu))
      return CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, nCode, wParam, lParam);

    Debug.WriteLine("Keybinding triggered!");
    return new IntPtr(1);
  }

  private static bool IsKeyDown(Keys key)
  {
    return (GetKeyState(key) & 0x8000) == 0x8000;
  }

  public enum HookType
  {
    WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13,
  }

  public delegate IntPtr HookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(HookType hookType, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, int dwThreadId);

  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  public static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx([Optional] IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  public static extern short GetKeyState(Keys nVirtKey);

  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
  public struct LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent
  {
    public int VirtualCode;
    public Keys Key => (Keys)VirtualCode;
    public int HardwareScanCode;
    public int Flags;
    public int TimeStamp;
    public IntPtr AdditionalInformation;
  }
}
```

Is there any way to avoid this strange behavior? Is this a bug?

Comment: GetKeyState checks the state of the key in your queue. But you are calling it from a low-level hook, which intercepts keys before the enter any queue (and even if they aren't destined for your queue).

Comment: Feature, not a bug.  [4th bullet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_keyboard_layout)

Comment: @HansPassant Ah interesting, that's definitely it! Is there a way to detect whether the right-side Alt key is treated as Ctrl + Alt or just regular Alt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @HansPassant mentioned, the AltGr key is present on certain keyboard layouts, like German and US International. It generates both Control and Alt when pressed.